# How to tell if credit balance is debt in Yodlee?

Tags: yodlee

The runningBalance parameter of Yodlee is always the current balance, or the previous statement balance.  Is there any way to tell whether the person is not paying the balance in full and incurring interest charges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RunningBalance is always the current balance. For credit cards Yodlee do provide statements which has the information about the statement balance(Amount due).Yodlee also scrapes the Last payment amount. This can be used if the person has paid the total amount in one shot. But if the person has made part payments then transactions can be used to determine if the person has paid the complete amount due or is incurring some interest charges for not paying the complete amount due.

Please check the data model pages which gives an overview of data elements scraped - 
Mani page -https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model

Card Statement -  https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Card_Statement_Data

Card Account - https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Card_Account_Data

Card Transaction - https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Card_Transaction_Data

Comment: How does one get a statement in the REST API?  I don't see anything like this anywhere.

Comment: you can get statement through the below API https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getItemSummaryForItem1

in parameters pass 

cobSessionToken,
userSessionToken,
itemId = itemId of credit card account,
dex.startLevel = 0,
dex.endLevel =0,
dex.extentLevels[0] = 0,
dex.extentLevels[1] = 4,

This will get the card statement as well in the response. Please let me know if any issue.